# create new variable name for each loop in a for loop

Tags: python, for-loop

How can i make a list's name change for each round in a for loop as below?

```
list_of_names=["A","B"]

for item in list_of_names:
    x_i=[1,2,3]
    print "done"
```

The for loop will have 2 loops so I would like 'i' in x_i to be x_A and x_B for each loop respectively.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-do-variable-variables-in-python see them as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
d={}    
for item in list_of_names:
    d['x_'+i]=[1,2,3]
    print "done"
```

you can use a dictionary to initialise the value

Comment: Don't use `dict` as a variable name(and 'u' is not a word).